# Dynamic html/php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an issue to figure out how to make dynamic pdf from html. I have a form, where user can add more fields if needed but i have no ideas how can i add it in html to be dynamical. Expected result:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyilw.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIz5N.png

Everything at the moment is hard-coded and not dynamic as i want to.

forma.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    div{
        padding:8px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="html_pdf.php">
<div id="p_scents">
    <p class="scent">
        <label for="p_scnts1">Input Value</label>
        <input type="text"  size="20" name="p_scnt1"/>
        <label for="p_more1">Input more</label>
        <input type="text"  size="20" name="p_more1"/>
        <a href="#" class="addScnt">Add</a>
        <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a>
    </p>
</div>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name="submit" id='submit'>
</form>

</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    $('.addScnt').bind('click', function() {
        var line=$('p:eq(0)',scntDiv).clone(true).insertAfter($(this).closest('p.scent'));
        $(':input:eq(0)',line).val('').focus();
        $i = 1;
        $('p',scntDiv).each(function(i){
            $(':input',this).each(function(){
                this.id=this.name = this.name.match(/^[a-z_]*/)[0]+(i+1);
            });
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('.remScnt').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

html_pdf.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$darbss = $_POST['p_scnt1'];
$stundass = $_POST['p_more1'];
$darbss2 = $_POST['p_scnt2'];
$stundass2 = $_POST['p_more2'];
$darbss3 = $_POST['p_scnt3'];
$stundass3 = $_POST['p_more3'];
}
?>

     ///////////////////////////
<body>
<div class="container">

<table class="table">
    // I WANT THIS TO REPEAT DYNAMYCALY
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $darbss ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $stundass  ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $darbss2 ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $stundass2  ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $darbss3 ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $stundass3  ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are dynamic inputs, so you need to make their names dynamic too

so you need to name them with [] so you can access them as loop

for example if you have first name and lastname it could be

```
<input type="text" name="myinputs[0][first_name]">
<input type="text" name="myinputs[0][last_name]">
```

use this as a the group of inputs so when you add another group you just increment the index

then you can access them from php as $_POST['myinputs']
you can loop it

```
foreach($_POST['myinputs'] as $input) {
    // first name will be $input['first_name']
    // last name will be $input['last_name']
}
```